# Mongoose Schema validation : block certain char in a string field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, validation, mongoose, schema

Is it possible to block a certain character in mongoose schema validation in server side?

I have this schema :

```
const address = {
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 25
  }
  country: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 25
  }
 postalcode: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 9
  }
}
```

I want to know if I can make sure in "City" field user can't enter "$" character. Can I do within the Schema or I need some other tools like [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup)?

Answer (score 1):

**MongoDB 3.2 Update**

Document validation is now supported natively by MongoDB.

Example from the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) :

```
db.createCollection( "contacts",
   { validator: { $or:
      [
         { phone: { $type: "string" } },
         { email: { $regex: /@mongodb\.com$/ } },
         { status: { $in: [ "Unknown", "Incomplete" ] } }
      ]
   }
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose has a built in validator for regex: the `match` field of property.

Also remember that Mongoose has arbitrary validation, and you should *almost* never be doing other validation *directly* prior to entering data into the database, because that *should* be repetitive. The point of a ORM (or, with MongoDB, an ODM), is to handle the data structure.

I'll show the use of `match`, and validators more generally, though, in this case using `match` is best.

```js
const address = {
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 25,

    // Built in match validator.
    match: /^[^$]+$/,

    // Single validator
    validate(value) {
        return !value.includes("$")
    },

    // Single validator with message
    validate: {
        validator(value) {
            return !value.includes("$")
        },
        message: "city must not include a dollarsign"
    },

    // Multiple validators
    validate: [
        {
            validator(value) {
                return !value.includes("$")
            },
            message: "city must not include a dollarsign"
        },
        {
            // Other validation logic
        }
    ]
  }
  country: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 25
  }
 postalcode: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 9
  }
}
```